# Select multiple column from multiple rows and return rows with total count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

ok, this is kind of complicated to explain, i will try my best, you are welcome to ask questions if you dont understand me.

i have a table desiged like this:

`TITLE | BRANCH | BRANCH1 | BRANCH2 | BRANCH3`

a `BRANCH` (any of them) might contain "bank","credit" and so on

what i want to do, is return rows with distinct branches and count, where the title equals "xxx"

something like:

`BANK | xxx Results`

`CREDIT | xxx Results`
and so on.

Comment: [Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table first. `BRANCH | BRANCH1 | BRANCH2 | BRANCH3` is not even in the [1FN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: i cant, its a system allready working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't alter your tables to conform to [1FN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), following should get you started

- `UNPIVOT` the columns using a `UNION ALL` giving you a resultset that conforms to [1FN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).
- Make this into a subselect
- Filter on the `TITLE` from this subselect
- `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` the results

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  BRANCH, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
          SELECT TITLE, BRANCH FROM MyTable 
          UNION ALL SELECT TITLE, BRANCH1 FROM MyTable 
          UNION ALL SELECT TITLE, BRANCH2 FROM MyTable 
          UNION ALL SELECT TITLE, BRANCH3 FROM MyTable 
        ) q
WHERE   TITLE = 'ATitle'        
GROUP BY
        BRANCH
```